# Perl one-liner if else logic

Tags: perl

I'm evaluating whether or not certain variables match expected values.  The variables are set in memory by a certain program, the values of which can be access from the shell with a custom program.

I'm piping the output of the shell command to awk to get the specific field I want and then I want to run it through perl to see if it matches the expected value.  For example,

```
ysgrp autostart | awk -F\: '{print $1}' | perl -e 'print {"True"} else {print "False"} if /on/'
```

However, I'm getting complaints from perl about compilation errors near "} else".  How does one handle if/then/else logic in a perl one-liner?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can't use an `else` condition in a postfix conditional. You can either use a ternary conditional operator like this:

```
perl -e 'print /on/ ? "True" : "False"'
```

Or use explicit blocks like this:

```
perl -e 'if ( /on/ ) { print "True" } else { print "False" }'
```

Answer (score 3):

This part:

```
awk -F\: '{print $1}' | perl -e 'print {"True"} else {print "False"} if /on/'
```

can be handled in perl (if I remember awk correctly):

```
perl -F/:/ -lane 'print $F[0] =~ /on/ ? "True" : "False"'
```

Note the use of the `-n` switch, without which your perl one-liner will not work. Also note the `-l` switch, which adds a newline to your print, which is something I assume you want. Otherwise your output will be something like:

```
TrueTrueTrueFalseTrueFalse
```

Comment: I realise the OP didn't end with a newline, but that's not really kosher. I'd use `perl -F: -lane'...'`

Comment: @ikegami 1: True, 2: I know, just fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

One does not, except by using the ternary `?:` operator; the `foo if bar` syntax does not support `else`.

Comment: I think you mean **ternary** operator ;o)

Comment: I don't know of many computer languages which have multiple ternary operators; the syntax is too annoying to parse.

Comment: Pedantry will save us all, I see.  Maybe I assume that the *customary* usage trumps the pedantic one?

Comment: @ikegami, I stand corrected. Yeah I suppose ternary operator is a generic term for an operator that takes three arguments much like '+' and '-' are binary operators. Don't think I've come across (m)any other ternary operators.

Comment: There is a general, customary usage across languages of "the ternary operator" meaning `?:` specifically, oddly enough.  This is largely because languages other than Perl don't have listops, much less mutant listops with restrictive prototypes.

Comment: "don't have listops, much less mutant listops with restrictive prototypes" is a weird way of saying "only have one".

Comment: It's a *detailed* way of saying it, in a misplaced attempt to satisfy the excessively pedantic.

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
 ... | perl -ne 'print /on/ ? "True" : "False"'
```

but please don't!  You'd be better off doing:

```
... | grep -qF on && echo True || echo False
```

Comment: This answer is best because of the addition of the "n" flag. Without it, the matching won't work as expected.